# Error in sending mail while using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email

I was building a website which can send mail to my account on the page view.

I have edited my `.env` file like this :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=example@example.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=example
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

**username and password is set as *example* for this question only**, on original file I have given my original name and email.
And my `mail.php` file looks like this:

```
'from' => [
    'address' => 'hello@example.com',
    'name' => 'Example',
],
```

With other function ^^

MyRoute file looks like this:

```
Route::get('/send', function() {
    Mail::send('email.send', ['name' => 'Its me'], function($message) {
        $message->to('example@example.com', 'Someone')->from('someone@somewhere.com')->subject('Worked');
    });
});
```

**Here also username and name is set as example || Its me on here only**, on original file I have given my original name and email.

And my `email/send.blade.php` file is having only `{{$name}}`

I used the [tutorial from youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KUJARfjOLW8) inorder to study this.

Still I get an error like this

[image: MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218]

How can I fix this error?
Please help me.

Comment: looks like you didn't declare your route to the controller/function that sends the email

Comment: @darham I didnt used any controller for it. Instead I used direct Route `function()`

Comment: just a thought, have you turned allow less secure apps on for gmail? This could be the cause as it would be pinging back an error i think?

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with emails. `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` means you're using a route method that isn't allowed. For instance, you're trying to POST to `/send` instead of GET. What is the URLs you're entering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try! This will work for sure

```
// Route::any : it means that it will allow all method like get,post,put,patch...
Route::any('/send', function() 
{
  return Mail::send('email.send', ['name' => 'Its me'], function($message) 
  {
     $name = "Name"; 
     $message->from('no-reply@xxxxx.com',$name); 
     $message->to('kroy.webxpert@gmail.com')->subject('Test Mail'); 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Try this it will work :

```
Route::match(['get','post'],'/send', function() {
    Mail::send('email.send', ['name' => 'Its me'], function($message) {
        $message->to('example@example.com', 'Someone')->from('someone@somewhere.com')->subject('Worked');
    });
});
```

OR

```
 Route::any('/send', function() {
        Mail::send('email.send', ['name' => 'Its me'], function($message) {
            $message->to('example@example.com', 'Someone')->from('someone@somewhere.com')->subject('Worked');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Now got another error. [Like this](http://prntscr.com/cscwgx). Please give solution to it also